# AppleScript color detection

Tags: colors, applescript, color-detection

I was working on the AppleScript below and I was trying to come up with a way to detect the change of a number in a game and then do a movement. What I've been trying to do is run a shell script from apple script that takes a screenshot of a pixel of the game and gets it hex color and I was trying to make it repeat until it saw if that the pixel of the number has changed by matching the outputs of the shell script to the pixel after the number gets changed. This doesn't work too well since I have to have a lot of hex colors to detect the number change and it also means there's a chance that it won't detect the color. Does anybody have a solution or any ideas to brainstorm? Thanks!

```
set defense to false

repeat while defense = false

(*Look at pixel*)
    set hexColor to do shell script "screencapture -R2387,1383,1,1 -t bmp $TMPDIR/test.bmp && 
             xxd -p -l 3 -s 54 $TMPDIR/test.bmp | 
             sed 's/\\(..\\)\\(..\\)\\(..\\)/\\3\\2\\1/'"

(*Detect change*)
    if (hexColor = "e09b9b") or (hexColor = "dd9e99") or (hexColor = "e19e9a") or (hexColor = "de9d9c") or (hexColor = "de9293") or (hexColor = "e48f8c") or (hexColor = "d8918b") or (hexColor = "e29a98") or (hexColor = "de9c99") or (hexColor = "de9d9b") or (hexColor = "e0908e") or (hexColor = "e18e8f") or (hexColor = "e29c9a") or (hexColor = "e69b9a") or (hexColor = "e29b9a") or (hexColor = "e09c9d") or (hexColor = "e29b9a") or (hexColor = "e19b9a") or (hexColor = "e49e9d") or (hexColor = "e29ba0") or (hexColor = "dd8f92") or (hexColor = "d99191") or (hexColor = "e39c9c") or (hexColor = "df999b") or (hexColor = "d88180") or (hexColor = "e09999") or (hexColor = "e49899") or (hexColor = "e29798") or (hexColor = "e19798") or (hexColor = "dd9995") or (hexColor = "df9c99") or (hexColor = "e49b99") or (hexColor = "dc9290") or (hexColor = "e29b9d") or (hexColor = "e19b9c") or (hexColor = "940d13") or (hexColor = "e39d99") or (hexColor = "e19f9a") or (hexColor = "de928e") or (hexColor = "e68f8f") or (hexColor = "e39d9d") or (hexColor = "e18f8f") then


(*Play Defense*)
        tell application "System Events"
            set defense to true
            key down "w"
            delay 0.7
            key up "w"
            delay 1
            key down "w"
            delay 0.5
            key up "w"
        end tell

    else

    end if

end repeat

set defense to false
```

Edit: I made the HexColorList and it works great thanks! Also, I included a screenshot of the two states I want to be able to tell a difference from. The screenshot of 40 seconds left is when I want to program to do nothing and then the screenshot of 39 seconds left I want it to run the "Play Defense" I have in the code (Keep in mind that the scores on the left and right aren't what I'm trying to track.

[image]

[image]

Edit 2: To clarify how the basketball game works what happens first is my character plays offense against an A.I. Character and I programmed that to work so my character scores and after he scores against the A.I., the shot clock resets back to 40 seconds and it starts when my character hands the ball off to the A.I. and then the shot clock starts and my character plays defense. So I am trying to make my code be able to wait until the shot clock starts when my character gives the ball to the A.I. and then start playing defense.

Comment: I'd get rid of the `if (hexColor = "e09b9b") or ... then` and replace it with `if hexColorList contains hexColor then` after creating: `set hexColorList to {"e09b9b", "dd9e99", "e19e9a", "de9d9c", "de9293", "e48f8c", "d8918b", "e29a98", "de9c99", "de9d9b", "e0908e", "e18e8f", "e29c9a", "e69b9a", "e29b9a", "e09c9d", "e29b9a", "e19b9a", "e49e9d", "e29ba0", "dd8f92", "d99191", "e39c9c", "df999b", "d88180", "e09999", "e49899", "e29798", "e19798", "dd9995", "df9c99", "e49b99", "dc9290", "e29b9d", "e19b9c", "940d13", "e39d99", "e19f9a", "de928e", "e68f8f", "e39d9d", "e18f8f"}`

Comment: IMHO You'd be better posting screencaptures of the area in the two different states so folks could see what you are looking for.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to do if the time is 38 seconds, or 43 seconds.

Comment: I expect a repeat loop, might be 'too tight' - and not give the other app time to update. You might get better results with a stay-open AppleScript app, using an `on idle` handler, instead. By adjusting the idle return value you can change the 'frequency' of events, e.g. by returning 1, your idle handler will run approximately every second. Not sure if this is fast enough for your use case.